# combine dictionary's values (saved as a list) of different keys if their values intersect

Tags: python-3.x

I have a large dictionary but I will simply it here. the dictionary looks like this:

```
d = {'key1': ['val1, val2, val3'],
     'key2': ['val4, val5, val6'],
     'key3': ['val7','val8','val3']}
```

and I need the dictionary to be like this:

```
{'key1': ['val1, val2, val3', 'val7', 'val8'], 
 'key2': ['val4, val5, val6']}
```

since key1 and key3 intersect with each other, I want to combine them in one key (which key doesn't matter)

Update:
the problem is like this, I have two separate dictionaries that have keys and values as shown. I tried to combine them together based on the intersections between them.
I used this:

```
d3= {}
for k1,v1 in d2.items():
    found_in_other_dict = False
    for k2,v2 in d1.items():
        if (k1 in v2) or (k1 == k2) or (k2 in v1) or (len(set(v1).intersection(set(v2))) > 0):
            d3.update({
                k1: list(set(v1+ v2 + [k1,k2]))
            })
            found_in_other_dict = True

        else:
            if k2 not in d3 and k2 not in [item for sublist in list(d3.values()) for item in sublist]:
                d3.update({
                    k2:list(set(v2 + [k2]))
                })


    if(not found_in_other_dict):
        if k1 not in d3 and k1 not in [item for sublist in list(d3.values()) for item in sublist]:
            d3.update({
                    k1:list(set(v1 + [k1]))
                })
```

after this, I had the issue asked in this post.
why they are not combined in the first place ?
let's say we have the following:

```
d1 = {'key1': ['val1','val2',
      'key2': ['val3','val4'}
d2 = {'key1': ['val3,'val6'}
```

when the code runs, it will deal with key1 in d1 separately. then it will combine k2 in d1 with k1 in d2.
that is why I have d3 dictionary which was represented by d in the begging of this question.

Comment: what if you had `'key4': ['val1', 'val4']`? where would those values go?

Comment: the original values are arranged in a way that doesn't let such thing happen. there might be another such as:'key4':
            ['val1', 'val8']
this key will be combined with key1 and key3.

Comment: Do you have anything you tried yet? At least a naive solution? We will be happy to offer improvements of find errors

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to ask a question according to the [ask] page. We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is on-topic here by visiting the [help/on-topic]; asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d = {'key1': ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'],
     'key2': ['val4', 'val5', 'val6'],
     'key3': ['val7', 'val8', 'val3']}  # this is your input

# compute the keys associated with each value in each of the value-lists
prep = {}
for k,vals in d.items():
    for val in vals:
        prep.setdefault(val, []).append(k)

for k in prep: prep[k].sort()

# this is the structure you want to return
answer = {}
for k, vals in d.items():
    answer.setdefault(k,[])
    s = set()
    for val in vals:
        for key in prep[val]:
            s = s.union(d[key])
    answer[k] = sorted(s)  # make sure the values are properly sorted, so that they can be compared properly

# delete the repeated entries
inverse = {}  # track which values are repeated across keys
for k,vals in answer.items():
    inverse.setdefault(tuple(vals), []).append(k)

for vals in inverse.values():
    for v in vals[1:]: answer.pop(v)
```

Output:

```
In [57]: answer                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[57]: 
{'key1': ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val7', 'val8'],
 'key2': ['val4', 'val5', 'val6']}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution, I don't want it throw away so just leave it here:

```
d = {'key1': ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'],
     'key2': ['val4', 'val5', 'val6'],
     'key3': ['val7','val8','val3']}

out = {}
while d:
    ik, iv = d.popitem()
    for k, v in out.items():
        intersection = k[1].intersection(iv)
        if intersection:
            v.extend(intersection)
            break
    else:
        out[(ik, frozenset(iv))] = iv
out = {k[0]: v for k, v in out.items()}


from pprint import pprint
pprint(out, width=60)
```

Prints:

```
{'key2': ['val4', 'val5', 'val6'],
 'key3': ['val7', 'val8', 'val3', 'val3']}
```